# In Python 2.7.10, put quotes around information from a CSV file to be used in a Google search

Tags: python, csv, google-search

My program takes the first and last name from a csv file row and puts it into a Google search argument along with another word. The search becomes:
John Doe teacher
I would like it to be:
"John Doe" + teacher 
How can I get the quotes and the + sign?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just try `+` or `join` method of string:

```
>>> name = "John Doe"
>>> deal_name = '"' + name + '" + ' + 'teacher'
>>> print deal_name
"John Doe" + teacher
>>> or_deal_name = ''.join(['"',name,'" + ','teacher'])
>>> print or_deal_name
"John Doe" + teacher
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I tried things like that but the complication is that I'm reading the names from a csv file.  Here is the code, I'm new to this forum, how to format it??                                                                   sword = raw_input('Enter your search term: ')
import webbrowser
new=2
import csv 
tabUrl="http://google.com/?#q=";
with open('c:\\users\\alice\my documents\short.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    names = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ' ')
    for row in names:
        term= ' '.join(row)
        webbrowser.open(tabUrl +term+ ' ' + sword, new=new)

Comment: I tried putting in ' " ' in the webbrowser.open line, no luck.  I'm not sure how to manipulate the term=' '.join(row) clause.